# I need a screenshot from a mac for an AIR app

Tags: macos, air

Can a kind-hearted mac user please spare a few moments to take a couple of screenshots of my first adobe air app and post it? Here is the link http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/apps/dreamhost-controller-using-api/. I have not tested my app on a mac but Adobe says it should work!

Comment: I need a screenshot of the AIR app not the webpage (sorry if it was not clear)

Comment: Di you use twitter? If not sign up and get good friends. i test my hooby prjects in diff OS with my Twitter friends.. Some of them whom I dont know ;-)

Comment: I hope this adds some credibility to the app, its approved by Adobe AIR marketplace http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/marketplace/index.cfm?event=marketplace.offering&offeringid=13181&marketplaceid=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go

[1](https://imgur.com/5jv7h.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TyO4.jpg)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rhpd.png)
[4](https://imgur.com/q4fnJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is a programming question but here it goes:

I believe you can use this site to get the screen shots you need.

http://browsershots.org/

Comment: Wow!  Really glad someone told me this site exists!  Thanks :)

Comment: That's a great site, but you can't use it for AIR apps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trusting this isn't a virus...but it works on OS X 10.5.7.   If you want a screenshot that looks like OSX there are plenty of themes for Ubuntu that will look exactly the same as Aqua.

Comment: Cool.. Can you please post screenshots? Definitely no virus in it.. It is also approved by Adobe AIR marketplace http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/marketplace/index.cfm?event=marketplace.offering&offeringid=13181&marketplaceid=1

Answer (score 0):

I'd go to the MacOSX channel (##macosx) on Freenode (irc.freenode.org) to ask for it.